# Getting too many Proguard warnings

Tags: proguard

I am trying to obfuscate my java application that is packed into a SINGEL jar. The application uses SWT gui libaries among others. I have duly listed them all in the Proguard configuration file via -libraryjars, but still I get too many warnings of the same type i.e.:
"Warning: library class org.eclipse.swt.accessibility.Accessible$10 extends or implements program class org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject"

What am doing wrong here??

Here is how my Proguard configuration looks like:

```
-injars 'D:\Tasks\Deployment\NEW - 30.06.2011\proguard4.6\lib\fevflex.jar'
-outjars 'D:\Tasks\Deployment\NEW - 30.06.2011\proguard4.6\lib\fevflex_out.jar'

-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\resources.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\jsse.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\jce.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\charsets.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\dnsns.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\localedata.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\commons-io-2.0.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\org.eclipse.core.commands_3.4.0.I20080509-2000.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.4.0.v20080421-2006.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\org.eclipse.jface_3.4.2.M20090107-0800.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\org.swtchart_0.6.0.v20090801.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\swt.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\swt_64bit.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\swtgraphics2d.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\testng.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\workspace\main\Code\demo\lib\xom-1.2.6.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\morelibs\c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\morelibs\jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\morelibs\log4j-1.2.6.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\morelibs\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.3.0.v3346.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\morelibs\xml-apis.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.1.R36x_v20100806.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.2.100.v20100503.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\morelibs\eclipseAdaptor.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\morelibs\org.eclipse.osgi_3.3.0.v20070530.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\morelibs\xerces-2.2.1.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.commons.logging_1.0.4.v201005080501.jar'

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-adaptresourcefilenames **.properties
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
-dontpreverify
-dontnote
-ignorewarnings
-printconfiguration 'D:\Tasks\Deployment\NEW - 30.06.2011\proguard4.6\lib\FLEX.pro'


-keep public class main.FEVFlex {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keep class nu.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep class org.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep class com.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > Warning: library class ... depends on program class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)

In this case, it looks like `org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject` is in your input jar `fevflex.jar`. You should remove it, or at least include it as part of a library jar.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you include both swt.jar and swt_64bit.jar in your libraries, while only one of these should be used at a time. Perhaps this is one of the reasons, why you are getting a lot of warnings.