# Proguard giving too many warnings for external libraries

Tags: android-proguard

I'm finishing up on my project and want to make it harder for `RE` but I'm new to Proguard and what I did was set `shrinkResources` and `minifyEnabled` in my Gradle to true but its giving me more than a thousand warnings.

I've looked around for a similar issue but the answer in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735181/getting-too-many-proguard-warnings) didn't help.

The Proguard file is as of now empty.

Comment: Please be willing to accept good edits here, The-Kamble. Rolling back to incorrect spellings is generally cause for moderator action, since it undoes good volunteer work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, what I did was use `-keep` for all classes giving warnings as in the link, and `-dontwarn` to remove the warnings. Just one thing, using `-dontwarn` alone might remove important classes.